# what's the difference between page cache and buffer cache?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory

In linux OS, you can type command "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_cache" to release memory, and you can type command "sync" to release the memory. And in linux kernel there are two kind of cache, one is page cache and the other is buffer cache, so what 's the difference?

Comment: [relevant](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics).

Comment: @Bratchley Why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: I don't know it well enough to write a good answer. Plus it's just something I found while googling this so it seem disingenuous to post an answer like I knew it to begin with.

Comment: thanks, it's helpful! Buffer cache has be combined into page cache.

Answer (score 3):

Since kernel 2.4 there is no difference between these cache types, there is only the page cache left.